# Creating LSI indexing with primary key as partition key and one attribute from DynamoDb document

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

If we have items in a table with following structure.

In DynamoDb can we use "a" as partition key and "aa" as sort key for querying?

```
{ 
  "a" : "",
  "b" : "",
  "c" : "",
  "d" : [ {
        "aa" : "",
        "bb" : ""
      },
      {
        "aa" : "",
        "bb" : ""
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use "a" as Partition key.

However, you can't use "aa" as SORT key. Sort key should be of Scalar type (String, Number, Boolean).

Keys of LSI/GSI can't be from Document data type (List, Map and Set) as well.

Comment: So any probable way as to query particular item in the itemlist of the document ?

Comment: Yes, you can use Query API only when partition key is available. If you know the partition key, you can include the additional filter criteria in FilterExpression including itemlist of the document. If you dont know the partition key, you can use Scan API with filter expressions. However, it is a full table scan and it is a costly operation.